# strange Out of memory behavior on php

Tags: php, memory-limit

hi am getting the following strange error

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 29097984) (tried to allocate
>   802454 bytes)

when i do `ini_get('memory_limit')` i got `256M`.

in the above error the script dies when it reaches `27M` ??

any suggestion am using shared hosting account.

Comment: And the line is???? I would guess you have an infinite loop/recursion in that line.

Comment: What code is running through 256M of your memory? :o
BTW, I think that when it says it tried to allocate 27M, it means that the script failed while allocating that particular chunk, there's probably already more memory being used.

Comment: @Indranil it says that 27M are already allocated and he wants to allocate 800kB

Comment: @TimWolla ah my bad, then. Sorry.

Comment: @TimWolla any suggestions here ?? what is wrong is there any apache settings can do this ? i mean overrides the php memory_limit ?

Comment: No, I don't have any idea. But you should probably show your code.

Comment: @TimWolla  while ($row[] = mysqli_fetch_object($res) ){}

Comment: Maybe the number / size of the results is very large?

Comment: @TimWolla let assume it's large why the script fails on 27M when the ini_get('memory_limit') return 256M, and as you said before at the time of the fatal it tried to allocate 800kb !!!! so it's way far from the limit !!

Comment: php's memory limit is just what php will enforce upon your script. It doesn't mean php itself will be allowed to request all the memory it wants.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to "debug" and get to the root of the problem.
I would start by increasing your php Memory limit to 526M

Use this to do that:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

This is more than enough to handle just about anything. If this still does not work, then I would look for infinite looping somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a shared host, it's incredibly likely that you don't have permissions to change the memory limit.  The problem is most likely that you are trying to create a huge array; you may want to try a different approach to whatever loop structure currently exists in your script.  But without code there isn't much else anyone can say to help.

Answer (score 0):

Even if memory limit is 256 megabytes, it does not mean your script will be able to allocate that much. The reason is that the RAM is shared between various processes. Some of them might have allocated lots of memory and left the OS with a few megabytes left, therefore your script cannot allocate as much as it needs regardless of the limit imposed.

What you should focus on is using least RAM possible. For database results such as yours, it's a good idea to use [SplFixedArray](http://www.php.net/SplFixedArray) rather than "regular" PHP array.